# Merge-Sort(array, first, last): Can first ever exceed last?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

```
MERGE-SORT(a[], first, last)
{
     if first >= last
         return

     mid = first + (last - first) / 2
     MERGE-SORT(a, first, mid)
     MERGE-SORT(a, mid + 1, last)
     MERGE(a, first, mid, last)
}
```

Is there a case where the first will ever be bigger than the last? If not, then the '>' in the if statement got no use I guess, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but... have you stepped through this with a debugger? Is this code someone else wrote, that you're trying to run? (the question you asked seems to be related to the functioning of a merge-sort).

Comment: Maybe not in the recursion case, but the top level could be called with `first > last`. Anyway, a `==` check is not faster than `>=`, so why not keep it safe?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, someone else wrote it. It's kinda the default merge-sort implementation, I have no problem with understanding how it functions, I was just confused about the '>' in the condition of the if statement because I didn't see a case where the first will ever be bigger than the last; but, I was only checking the recursion case as our friend mentioned and I forgot that this case may occur in the top level when the function is initially called.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes I was only keeping track of the recursion and forgot that it may occur in the top level as you mentioned, thank you very much.